# Fieller's Theorem Degrees of Freedom

Tags: confidence-interval, degrees-of-freedom, ratio

In a [previous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21078) question I was trying to figure out how to compute the confidence interval of a ratio. Having come to the conclusion that the correct way to do this is [Fieller's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieller's_theorem), I realize I'm very unsure about my  interpretation of the degrees of freedom.

I'm trying to compute confidence intervals for a speedup -- computed as a ratio:

$$ 
\frac{\text{time mean}_{\text{1 thread}}}{\text{time mean}_{n \text{ threads}}} 
$$

Each thread count has $k$ samples.

I want to say I need 1 degree of freedom here... but I also have been known to be wrong in these things before...

Comment: Online documentation indicates the degrees of freedom will be $a+b-2,$ where $a$ is sample size of numerator and $b$ is sample size of denominator. Why do you think it should be 1 degree of freedom?

Comment: A day later, I now... don't really recall. :S I grabbed my stats book and agree that $a + b - 2$  is reasonable (though, it doesn't have Fieller's Theorem).